# How to store multiple input values and tie it with a specific index of an array?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

I am currently trying to answer a tutorial exercise involving a basic customer ticketing system.

The program goes like you input a customer's name, the movies they want to watch, how many tickets they want, etc. and I stored these customer names inside a list. I have managed to finish everything on the tutorial exercise such as adding more movies to the list and the customer being able to choose multiple movies whilst everything is calculated accordingly. It also contains a menu, so multiple customer data can be input after another.

However, the last part proved to be challenging for me. What it wants is for the program to be able to fetch the customer's "purchase history", meaning I have to display an output of everything they have bought and selected so far by typing their name.

I am currently trying to figure out what to do but I am at lost at the moment. Is there a way for you to store the input values on a specific variable without it getting overwritten? I tried using dictionaries, but it would get overwritten if a new customer comes along.

Can you guys offer me some suggestions on what to do or what to read? I'm keen to learn and finish this tutorial exercise after attempting it for a couple of days already. I haven't also touched OOP yet if that is the key to this exercise.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1):

I found this example code, it is very simple one, but you can use this logic to show purchase history of the customers.

```
class Customer:
    def __init__(self, name, movies, tickets):
        self.name = name
        self.movies = movies
        self.tickets = tickets

customers = []  # Create an empty list to store customer instances

while True:
    # Get customer's name, movie choices, and tickets
    customer_name = input("Enter customer name: ")
    movies = input("Enter movies (comma-separated): ").split(',')
    tickets = int(input("Enter number of tickets: "))
    
    # Create a Customer instance and add it to the list
    customer = Customer(customer_name, movies, tickets)
    customers.append(customer)
    
    # Ask if the user wants to continue adding customers
    more_customers = input("Add more customers? (yes/no): ")
    if more_customers.lower() != 'yes':
        break

# Display purchase history for a specific customer
search_name = input("Enter customer name to search: ")
found_customer = None
for customer in customers:
    if customer.name == search_name:
        found_customer = customer
        break

if found_customer:
    print(f"Purchase history for {found_customer.name}:")
    print("Movies:", found_customer.movies)
    print("Tickets:", found_customer.tickets)
else:
    print("Customer not found.")
```